# What happens when authenticating through a phishing attack with FIDO U2F tokens

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, one-time-password

So I have looked around and haven't found this anywhere.  What happens when the response server is a phishing site with FIDO U2F tokens?

Basically, if login just fails, I would assume that the user would try again a couple of times, assume that something is broken and fall back to using OTP 2 factor which defeats the purpose.

The other option would be that there would be some form of notification, which would be helpful and logical, but I havent seen anything saying that this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up [asking Yubico about this through twitter](https://twitter.com/Yubico/status/619613089273516032). The authentication currently just fails, but a manufacture could add a screen to a key that would give a more helpful notification.

The default user behavior will be to try again and then circumvent the security key through a one time password, which does allow man in the middle attacks.  So an important side note will be to teach users to *not* ever use the one time password option.